# How to pipe one response to another response in Express

Tags: node.js, rest, express

Is there a way that I can dispatch, say, a REST request inside of an Express route handler and then either intercept the response to apply custom logic or pipe it through as-is the `res`?

I imagine that I could copy all of the different parts of the REST response into `res` (i.e. headers, status code, body, etc.) but then again I don't know all of the parts that I would need to copy to clone the response exactly. Some sort of automatic mechanism is preferable.

```
import { Client } from 'node-rest-client-promise';

app.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  const client = new Client();
  const { response } = await this.client.getPromise(url);

  switch (response.statusCode) {
    case 404:
      // Intercept and replace code and body.
      res.status(200).send('Other results');
      return;
    default:
      // Otherwise pipe REST response to res.
      response.pipe(res);
      return;
  }
});
```

This code snippet ends up just returning a 200 code with an empty body for any type of REST response besides a 404.

> NOTE: It's not necessary that I use `node-rest-client-promise` but I would prefer to for simplicity.

Comment: To `.pipe()`, you need a request library that puts the response into a node.js stream.  It does not appear that node-rest-client-promise does that.  The `request()` library does offer a stream and even shows you [how to use `.pipe()` here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#streaming).

Answer (score 0):

I use the `request` package to do my HTTP request and then just do `response.pipe(res);` as you wrote.
Works just fine